# COUNTIFS function returning error in value

Tags: countif, excel-2016

I am putting together an COUNTIFS function on a spreadsheet.  Below is the function in the cell.  The problem is that I am getting an "error in value".

```
=COUNTIFS(PI,+AX3,Brian,+AX4,Directorate,+AW5)
```

The PI, Brian and Directorate are named ranges.  I think the problem is with Brian, +AX4. Although, if I have this on its own it returns a value.  I have tried the named range manually but that seems to fail. I'm not sure why it is falling down. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the named ranges all exactly the same size?  Try it with explicitly specified ranges instead of named ranges. Also, what is the *exact* error message?

Comment: Yes your right ashleedawg! The ranges for PI and Directorate are exactly the same.  It's just the Brian range was out by one cell.  Ashleedawg can you copy and paste your response and I will upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the three named ranges aren't all the same size, or they are incorrectly [referenced](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/refer-to-named-ranges?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Try it with ***explicitly specified ranges*** instead of named ranges to determine which one doesn't match the others.

**Microsoft Video Lesson : [Advanced IF Functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Advanced-IF-functions-17341cef-510d-4d60-a657-913f878fdacf?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)**